# Ansible: How to write a YAML Playbook as a JSON or Python data array?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have some experience with JSON and Python, so I would like to visualize an Ansible YAML playbook as a regular Python or JSON inline data structure. Is it possible to write the entire contents of a YAML file as an inline data structure consisting of lists and dictionaries? If so, could I also use whitespace to make it easier to read?

Example:

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:
  - name: ensure apache is at the latest version
    yum:
      name: httpd
      state: latest
  - name: write the apache config file
    template:
      src: /srv/httpd.j2
      dest: /etc/httpd.conf
```

Which becomes:

```
---
[{hosts: webservers, remote_user: root, gather_facts: true, tasks: [{name: ensure apache is at the latest version, yum: {name: httpd, state: latest}}], [name: write the apache config file, template: {src: /srv/httpd.j2, dest: /etc/httpd.conf}]}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you cannot represent YAML as JSON, because JSON is subset
of YAML. E.g. YAML tags and anchors cannot be expressed in JSON, and
the restrictions on keys in JSON object are extremely severe, whereas
YAML essentially can have any node as key in a mapping.

Python can represent YAML completely, if not then `ruamel.yaml` could
not round-trip YAML files. And so you can generate all YAML data
structures from scratch using regular Python constructs and then dump
them to YAML. For tagged constructs this is however not completely
trivial. You also have to consider that no library gives you complete
control over the syntactic representation, and indentation is normally
the same for all mappings and all sequences (or even the same for all
collections).

If your YAML doesn't contain tags, like your example, then the YAML can be loaded as the
regular Python constructs such as dicts, lists and primitives such as
strings, integers, float, datetime.datetime, boolean. You can just
load the YAML and print the data structure:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """---
- hosts: webservers
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:
  - name: ensure apache is at the latest version
    yum:
      name: httpd
      state: latest
  - name: write the apache config file
    template:
      src: /srv/httpd.j2
      dest: /etc/httpd.conf
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print(data)
```

which gives:

```
[{'hosts': 'webservers', 'remote_user': 'root', 'gather_facts': True, 'tasks': [{'name': 'ensure apache is at the latest version', 'yum': {'name': 'httpd', 'state': 'latest'}}, {'name': 'write the apache config file', 'template': {'src': '/srv/httpd.j2', 'dest': '/etc/httpd.conf'}}]}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Good information about YAML having extra value types (anchor and tag) than JSON and Python.